# Sonarqube Integration with External Elastic Search

Tags: sonarqube

We have installed sonarqube docker image of 7.9.1 in openshift cluster. Related to the integration of Elastic search we have the below questions.
1. Is it Possible to integrate Sonarqube application application with External 
Elasticsearch?
2. If so, Can you provide us the steps to be done from the sonarqube docker image?